# Creating an Element with JavaScript inside a Table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a table with content from a database which I can delete or edit. So I want to create two buttons in the last cell of every row (one for delete and the other one for editing the content).

I've tried this:

```html
<td>${test.id}</td>
<td>${test.name}</td>
<td>
  <script>
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    x.setAttribute("value", "edit");
    x.setAttribute("id", "edit" + $ {
      test.id
    });
    document.body.appendChild(x);
  </script>
</td>
</tr>
```

but the buttons were created at the top of the page...

Do i habe to create the whole table in one script?

Comment: Instead of appending it to `document.body`, you should append it to whatever your table, or table row, is that you want it to be in.

Comment: sound's obvious, but how can i append an element to a cell?^^

Comment: Select the cell, either with an ID or dynamically. If the table's id is something like `my_table`, then you can select it with a jQuery selector: `$("#my_table tr td")` would return all `td`s in your table.

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel There is no jQuery on this question, so your comment full of jQuery code isn't helping the OP :)

Comment: Some people might tag jQuery as just `javascript`. In replace of a jQuery selector, however, you can use `document.querySelectorAll([query string]);` which functions almost exactly identically to the `$([query string])` of jQuery.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok thank you all for your help, but I did it by myself by appending it to the last cell:

```js
< script >
  var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "submit");
x.setAttribute("value", "edit");
x.setAttribute("id", "edit" + $ {
  test.id
});
document.getElementById("datatable").lastChild.lastChild.appendChild(x); < /script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are creating the buttons with javascript. Write the HTML like normal, then bind your events later in the document. The approach you show is not necessary, and not a good way to approach it either.

A better route would be to use event delegation so you only bind one event to the table. As a button is clicked, you examine the target of the event, and if it is a button, act accordingly.

There's no reason to use javascript to create the elements no matter what approach for event binding you use. Below, I will illustrate using delegation.

Another quick note, if you're going to do a lot of other javascript, you may be better off getting a library like jQuery. Since you didn't indicate that you have jQuery, the code below is "vanilla" javascript.

```js
// quickie cross-browser events
function addEvent(element, evnt, funct){
  if (element.attachEvent)
   return element.attachEvent('on'+evnt, funct);
  else
   return element.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
}

// bind an event to the table, capture any clicks
addEvent(
    document.getElementById('datatable'),
    'click',
    function (e) {
        var targetElement = e.target;
        
        // we're only worried about clicks on button elements
        if (targetElement.tagName != 'BUTTON')
            return true;

        var id = targetElement.dataset.id;
        // handle edit button click
        if ((' '+targetElement.className+' ').indexOf(' edit-button ') > -1) {
            alert('edit button for #'+id+' clicked');
            return false;
        }
      
        // handle delete button click
        if ((' '+targetElement.className+' ').indexOf(' delete-button ') > -1) {
            alert('delete button for #'+id+' clicked');
            return false;
        }
    }
);
```

```html
    <table id="datatable">
        <tr>
          <td>${test.id}</td>
          <td>${test.name}</td>
          <td>
            <button class="edit-button" data-id="{$test.id}">edit</button>
            <button class="delete-button" data-id="{$test.id}">delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      
        <tr>
          <td>${test.id}</td>
          <td>${test.name}</td>
          <td>
            <button class="edit-button" data-id="{$test.id}">edit</button>
            <button class="delete-button" data-id="{$test.id}">delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ... etc -->
    </table>
```

**Related Reading**

- Data attributes - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes
- Introduction to events - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html
- Event delegation - http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Comment: thx for your help, but i don't get how your script works? and i also get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attachEvent' of null"!
I want to submit the id and other form objets by submit with this button, will this work?

Comment: @BernhardSchneeweiß You place the javascript at the end of the document, or in a separate file that you include with a `<script>` tag at the end of the document. Alternately, you can call it from the body's onload event. I highly suggest you take a look at some basic HTML/Javascript tutorials, the way you're approaching this problem is making it harder on yourself.

Answer (score -2):

You'll need a script later to attach event handlers, but to get your code to work:

```html
<td>${test.id}</td>
<td>${test.name}</td>
<td>
  <input type="submit" value="edit" id="edit${test.id}" />
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If you're going to inline it, just write the html. Additionally, document.write is quite dangerous as it can overwrite the whole document if the document is closed.